# Using Euler's equation

Tags: vector-analysis, fluid-dynamics

An incompressible inviscid ﬂuid, under the inﬂuence of gravity, has the velocity ﬁeld
$$\textbf u = (− \cos(x)\sin(y), \, \, \sin(x)\cos(y), \, \, 0)$$
with the $z$-axis vertically upwards, where $g$ is the acceleration due to gravity.

Use Euler’s equation to ﬁnd the pressure $p$.

In my notes, the equation is given as $$ \frac { D \textbf u }{Dt} = \frac{\partial \textbf u }{\partial t} + (\textbf u \, \, . \triangledown ) \textbf u = - \frac1 {\rho} \triangledown p - g \textbf k$$ but what is $\textbf k$? I have also seen it written as $$ \frac { D \textbf u }{Dt} = \frac{\partial \textbf u }{\partial t} + (\textbf u \, \, . \triangledown ) \textbf u = - \frac1 {\rho} \triangledown p + \frac1{\rho} \textbf F $$ but what is $\textbf F$?

In our question, $\partial \textbf u / \partial t =0$ and I found $(\textbf u \, \, . \triangledown ) \textbf u$ is equal to: $$(- \sin (x) \cos (x) \sin ^2 (y) + \sin ^2 (x) \sin (y) \cos (y) , \sin (x) \cos (x) \sin ^2 (y) - \sin ^2 (x) \sin (y) \cos (y) , 0)$$

What do we do next?

Comment: Not knowing anything about this... but $\bf k$ is surely the vertical $(0,0,1)$ vector if $g$ is acceleration due to gravity $\bf F$. Also, I think you must have goofed in your calculus calculation... e.g., in your notation, for the $x$ coordinate of ${\bf u} = (u_1, u_2, u_3) $:
$$ {Du_1\over Dt} =  {\partial u_1\over \partial x} x' + {\partial u_1\over \partial y} y'.$$
So: 
$$ {Du_1\over Dt}  = \sin x \sin y \,(- \cos x \sin y) - \cos x \cos y\, (\sin x \cos y ) = -\sin x \cos x .$$

Comment: (cont) $Du_2/Dt$ is similar - at that point it is fairly straight-forward to solve for $p$ - if I am understanding anything at all...

Comment: Sorry - I should have added that $x' = u_1$ and $y' = u_2$ above; I wanted to emphasize the link to the partials....

Comment: @peterag thanks, is pressure $p$ a vector? If its being a product of $\triangledown$, then it must be right?

Comment: @peterag I got my final answer as $$ p = - \frac {\rho}4 \big( \cos (2x) + \cos (2y) \big) - \rho g z$$ would this be correct?

Comment: You obviously answered your own question about $p$ - it's a scalar function - and I think your final answer looks good too, unless we both screwed up...